# Low speed SQL query in balance sheet calculation

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-performance, accounting, sqlperformance

I am using Tarazc4 sp to calculate the balance sheet of my application but it is very time consuming when my records reached to 50000 (time out error), please help on this !! it is out of my mind now !!!

```
SELECT * 
INTO #levels
FROM dbo.topics_getlevel()

SELECT * 
INTO #t1 
FROM accounting.documentdetail 
WHERE accounting.documentdetail.date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate

SELECT * 
FROM 
   (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
        Accounting.Topics.Code, Accounting.Topics.TopicID, Accounting.Topics.ParentID,  
        Accounting.Topics.Description, 
        (SELECT Debit
         FROM dbo.SubTopics_GetSum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID, @FromDate, @ToDate) AS SubTopics_GetSum_2) AS Debit,
        (SELECT Credit
         FROM dbo.SubTopics_GetSum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID, @FromDate, @ToDate) AS SubTopics_GetSum_1) AS Credit, 
        (CASE 
            WHEN ((SELECT     Credit
                              FROM          dbo.subtopics_getsum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID,@FromDate,@ToDate)) -
                          (SELECT     Debit
                             FROM         dbo.subtopics_getsum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID,@FromDate,@ToDate))) < 0 THEN
                          ((SELECT     Debit
                              FROM          dbo.subtopics_getsum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID,@FromDate,@ToDate)) -
                          (SELECT     Credit
                             FROM         dbo.subtopics_getsum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID,@FromDate,@ToDate))) ELSE 0 END) AS ResDEBIT, (CASE WHEN
                          ((SELECT     Credit
                              FROM          dbo.subtopics_getsum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID,@FromDate,@ToDate)) -
                          (SELECT     Debit
                             FROM         dbo.subtopics_getsum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID,@FromDate,@ToDate))) > 0 THEN
                          ((SELECT     Credit
                              FROM          dbo.subtopics_getsum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID,@FromDate,@ToDate)) -
                          (SELECT     Debit
                             FROM         dbo.subtopics_getsum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID,@FromDate,@ToDate))) ELSE 0 END) AS ResCREDIT,(select [Level] from #Levels where TopicID=Accounting.Topics.TopicID) as [Level]
FROM         Accounting.Topics Left OUTER JOIN
                      #t1 ON Accounting.Topics.TopicID = #t1.TopicFK

GROUP BY Accounting.Topics.TopicID, Accounting.Topics.ParentID, Accounting.Topics.Code, Accounting.Topics.Description

ORDER BY Accounting.Topics.TopicID
)
t2
```

--------------------------------END Tarazc4

and used " dbo.subtopics_getsum " function in Tarazc4 sp to get sum of each account ,check it out plz :

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[SubTopics_GetSum]

(
@TopicID int,@FromDate char(10),@ToDate char(10)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
     WITH cte AS (
     SELECT  T1.TopicID, T1.Code, T1.Description, T1.ParentID, 
     T1.ParentID AS NewParentID, 
     CAST(T1.Code AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS TopicCode, 
     CAST(T1.Description AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS TopicDescription,
     isnull((Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit),0) AS  Debit,
     isnull((Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit),0) AS Credit
     FROM Accounting.Topics AS T1 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Accounting.DocumentDetail ON T1.TopicID = Accounting.DocumentDetail.TopicFK
     where (Accounting.DocumentDetail.date between @FromDate and @ToDate) 
     and NOT EXISTS(
          SELECT    T2.TopicID, T2.Code, T2.Description, T2.ParentID, 
          isnull((Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit),0) AS Debit,
          isnull((Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit),0) AS Credit
          FROM Accounting.Topics AS T2 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN
          Accounting.DocumentDetail 
          ON T2.TopicID = Accounting.DocumentDetail.TopicFK
          WHERE (Accounting.DocumentDetail.date between @FromDate and @ToDate) 
          and (ParentID = T1.TopicID)
     )
     UNION ALL                          
     SELECT c.TopicID, c.Code, c.Description, c.ParentID, T1.ParentID AS NewParentID, 
     CAST(T1.Code AS nvarchar(MAX)) + c.TopicCode AS TopicCode, 
     CAST(T1.Description AS nvarchar(MAX)) + ' - ' + 
     c.TopicDescription AS TopicDescription,
     c.Debit AS Debit,c.Credit  AS Credit
     FROM cte AS c 
     INNER JOIN Accounting.Topics AS T1 
     ON T1.TopicID = c.NewParentID
     )

     select 
     isnull(sum(Debit),0)+
     isnull(
       (select sum(debit) from accounting.documentdetail 
        where (Accounting.DocumentDetail.date between @FromDate and @ToDate) 
       and topicfk=@TopicID)
     ,0) as Debit,
     isnull(Sum(Credit),0)+
     isnull(
        (select sum(credit) from accounting.documentdetail 
         where (Accounting.DocumentDetail.date between @FromDate and @ToDate) 
         and topicfk=@TopicID)
     ,0) as Credit 
     from cte as c
     WHERE     (NewParentID = @TopicID)
)
```

Actually , my topics and documents table are like following image , and I just need to calculate the balance sheet of my topics from documentdetail table and show it like hierarchy of my topics (parent-childs) !!!!
[image]

Comment: Phew - huge messy code! Just a word of general advice: using functions that do database access inside a query is most often very bad for performance ...

Comment: There is really nothing for it - you need to refactor your code to not use that function, and also refactor it to not just call the function repeatdly in each column. I'm still trying to get my head around it all. For example you dump document detail into #t1 but you can't use that in your function.

Comment: but I calculate the Balance of each account with that function, any suggestions instead ?? @marc_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see `dbo.subtopics_getsum(Accounting.Topics.TopicID,@FromDate,@ToDate)` over and over in your columns. As a nasty workaround you could also dump that into a temp table like #t1, although it might be that it's already cached sufficiently.

Also I don't see the need for `TOP (100) PERCENT` although it probably makes no difference. Was this copied out of a view at some stage?

You really need to refactor this code properly.

Comment: it is not copy at all, check the question again I put my tables to make the question clear , help on this plz

Comment: OK that's fine. Do you know the actual purpose of TOP 100 Percent in this query? It's not important it probably doesn't affect performance anyway. If you want to improve performance you need to move the balance logic out of the function and into the query. This requires a total rewrite.

Comment: How many 'topics' do you generate? all/most of them? Because your function is picking a single topic and generating that one over and over. You might be better off generating all topics in one go rather than inside a repeatedly called function.

Comment: All topics must be generated , I call the function per topic because it should calculate the each topics childes balances and return sum of them to the parent topic . you mean if put the getsum codes inside the tarazc4 it will improve the performance????

Comment: If you remove the functions (move the getsum code into taracz4) it will most likely improve performance. But if you have a parent child relationship you should instead calculate only leaf level values and summarise them up the parent/child hierarchy, which is quite a change to your code.

Comment: Perhaps the first step is to create a new stored procedure based on [dbo].[SubTopics_GetSum] which creates ALL leaf level topic balances in ONE SQL statement (not looping around topics but do it in one go). This gives you a basis to then generate balances further up the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Finally , I come up with this code and improves my performance amazingly but please check it out if there are any other points that can help to improve the performance ???

```
select * into #tleaf from(select *,(CASE WHEN (Credit-Debit) < 0 THEN (Debit-Credit) ELSE 0 END) AS ResDEBIT,(CASE WHEN(Credit-Debit) > 0 THEN(Credit-Debit) ELSE 0 END) AS ResCREDIT from (SELECT  Accounting.AllTopicsCTE.TopicID, Accounting.AllTopicsCTE.ParentID, Accounting.AllTopicsCTE.Code, Accounting.AllTopicsCTE.Description, isnull(sum(Debit),0) as Debit,isnull(sum(Credit),0) as Credit
                             from Accounting.AllTopicsCTE  LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Accounting.DocumentDetail ON Accounting.AllTopicsCTE.TopicID = Accounting.DocumentDetail.TopicFK
                      where Accounting.DocumentDetail.Date between @FromDate and @ToDate
                      group by Accounting.AllTopicsCTE.TopicID, Accounting.AllTopicsCTE.ParentID, Accounting.AllTopicsCTE.Code, Accounting.AllTopicsCTE.Description) t0 
                     )t1
               select TopicID,ParentID,Code,Description,0 as Debit,0 as Credit,0 as ResDebit,0 as ResCredit into #tmain from Accounting.Topics where TopicID not in(select TopicID from #tleaf)      

                   --#tresult 
                    select * into #tresult from 
                    (select * from #tmain
                     union all
                     select * from #tleaf) b;
                     --------------------------------------------------------------
WITH HierarchicalCTE AS
(
    SELECT TopicID, ParentID, Code, Description,
           Debit,Credit,ResDebit,ResCredit, 0 AS LEVEL
    FROM #tresult i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i.TopicID, i.ParentID, i.Code, i.Description,
           cte.Debit, cte.Credit,cte.ResDebit,cte.ResCredit,
           cte.LEVEL + 1
    FROM HierarchicalCTE cte join
         #tresult i
         ON i.TopicID = cte.ParentID
)
select TopicID, ParentID, Code, Description,
       sum(Debit) as Debit, sum(Credit) as Credit,sum(ResDebit) as ResDEBIT,sum(ResCredit) as ResCREDIT,(select [Level] from #Levels where TopicID=HierarchicalCTE.TopicID) as [Level]
from HierarchicalCTE
group by TopicID, ParentID, Code, Description
                     ------------------------------
```

Comment: Two things I noticed: 1. It's bad practice to use `select *`. It invites errors when columns are added or removed. 2. You are left joining to a table then filtering on it afterwards, effectively making it an inner join. Performance _might_ be improved by converting unneeded outer joins to inner joins. As you can see removing the function as I suggested has improved performance. The next thing you can probably do is get a query plan (CTRL-L) and see if it suggests any indexes.

Comment: Tahnks dear @ElectricLlama